# History replace in componentWillMount

Tags: react-router

Given the following as a mixin for a Authenticated component:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { authenticated, location: nextLocation } = this.props
  const { replace } = this.context.router
  if (!authenticated)
    replace({ pathname: '/login', state: { nextLocation } })
}
```

When server side rendering is performed I would expect the history to transition to `/login`, however this is not the case and no change occurs. This works fine in the browser.

Is this beyond what react-router and/or history is capable of achieving?

What is the correct way of performing a component level redirect for server rendering?

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't found a great way of doing this. If you have a `<Redirect />` or `<IndexRedirect />` then `match` will return this via the `redirectLocation` param. But sometimes you need to take into account logic that simple routing can't manage, such as your `isAuthenticated` example.

Maybe you could do it via the redux store – if you want to redirect then dispatch some action that says where to redirect in your redux store. Then after calling `loadOnServer`, check the store and if there's a redirect set then do it... You could probably make a nice container component that wraps this up into some kind of `context` function call.